# Como obter apenas um trecho da saída de um comando

Tags: bash, shell-script

Como faço para mostrar apenas o numero da versão? Exemplo:

```
GIT_VERSION=$(git --version)

echo $'git instalado com sucesso! Na versao: '$GIT_VERSION$'\n'
```

A saída eu desejo que seja "Na versao: 1.20.2". Já tentei com array e o `sed` mas não consegui.

Comment: Tente utilizar `git --version | awk '{ print $3 }'`. :)

Comment: funcionou! obrigado!!!

Answer (score 1):

Você pede especificar um range de caracteres que deseja imprimir.

Tente:

```
echo $'git instalado com sucesso! Na versao: '${GIT_VERSION:12:17}$'\n'
```

Explicando `${VAR_NOME:Primeiro caractere a ser impresso: ultimo a ser impresso}`

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que a saída do comando `git --version` é algo como `git version 1.2.3`, então no fundo é uma questão de obter o trecho final. Tem várias formas de fazer isso.

Uma é usando o [comando `cut`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html):

```
GIT_VERSION=$(git --version | cut -d" " -f 3)
```

A opção `-d" "` indica que o espaço (denotado por `" "`) deve ser usado como separador, ou seja, a saída será separada em 3 partes: `git`, `version` e o número da versão. Em seguida, `-f 3` indica que queremos somente o terceiro campo, que no caso é o número da versão.

---

Outra alternativa (já [indicada nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/482915/como-colocar-apenas-o-numero-da-vers%C3%A3o-em-bash-shell-script#comment903074_482915)) é usar [`awk`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/awk.1p.html):

```
GIT_VERSION=$(git --version | awk '{print $3}')
```

A ideia é a mesma do `cut`, a diferença é que o espaço já é o separador *default*, e o terceiro campo é acessado por `$3`.

---

Também é possível com [`sed`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html):

```
GIT_VERSION=$(git --version | sed -e 's/.* \([^ ][^ ]*\)[ ]*$/\1/')
```

Mas eu acho desnecessariamente complicado - apesar de funcionar, [regex nem sempre é a melhor solução](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).
Mas enfim, a regex pega uma [sequência de caracteres que não são espaços](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) (`[^ ]`) no [final da string](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) (`$`), e coloca em um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (denotado pelos parênteses). E na substituição, eu uso somente o valor do grupo (`\1`), ignorando o restante da linha.

---

Você pode ainda transformar a saída do comando em um array:

```
dados=($(git --version))
GIT_VERSION=${dados[2]}
```

Os parênteses a mais em volta do comando transformam a saída em um [array](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-use-arrays-in-bash-script), e a versão estará na terceira posição (lembrando que a primeira é zero, por isso usei o índice 2).

Não é tão direto quanto as opções anteriores, e é mais útil se você precisar de todos os campos separadamente. Mas se quiser somente o número da versão, as 2 primeiras opções me parecem melhores.